# Determine all the numbers $c$ which satisfy the conclusion of Rolle’s theorem and the mean value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine all the numbers $c$ which satisfy the conclusion of Rolle’s theorem for $g(x)=2x-x^2-x^3$ on $[-2,1]$

My attempt:

$g$ is continuous on $[-2,1]$ and the derivative $g’$ exist at every point $c\in (-2,1)$, and $g(-2)=g(1)=0$.

Then there exists at least $c\in (-2,1)$ such that $g’(c)=0$.

We have that $g’(x)=2-2x-3x^2$.

$g’(c)=0$

$\implies 3c^2+2c-2=0$

$\implies c=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{7}}{3}\in (-2,1)$

> Determine all the numbers $c$ which satisfy the conclusion of the mean value theorem for $h(x)=8x+e^{-3x}$ on $[-2,3]$.

$h$ is continuous on $[-2,3]$ and has a derivative in $(-2,3)$. Then there exists at least one point $c\in (-2,3)$ such that

$5h’(c)=h(3)-h(-2)$ ... (1)

We have that $h’(x)=8-3e^{-3x}$

By substitute in (1).

$5(8-3e^{-3c})=(8(3)+e^{-3(3)})-(8(-2)+e^{-3(-2)})$

$40-15e^{-3c}=40+e^{-9}-e^6$

$e^{-3c}=\frac{e^6-e^{-9}}{15}$

$c=\frac{1}{3} \ \ln(\frac{e^6-e^{-9}}{15})=1.097\in (-2,3)$

Is that true, please? Thanks.

Comment: Everything is right except the last point, your $c$ should have a negative factor because you divide by $-3$ not $3$, so $c \approx -1.097$. You can check your answer by evaluating $h'(-1.097)$ and compare it to $\frac{h(3)-h(-2)}{5}$ numerically. You will see they are almost exactly the same (because $c$ is approximated)

Comment: @Hushus46 Thank you so much, your comment is so helpful.